# Writing 2 variables in a legend with 2 different plots

Tags: matlab, plot, legend

I want to write 2 variables in my legend.

```
legend('raw', 'suggested-signal: %f , suggested-filter: %f',a,b);
```

I know this is wrong, but I don't know how else to include 2 variable in the legend. I have a way for 1 variable but not two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get your intention correctly, you miss the `sprintf`:

```
legend('raw', sprintf('suggested-signal: %f, suggested-filter: %f',x,y));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would dome something like this:

```
legend('raw', ['suggested-signal: ' num2str(a)]', ['suggested-filter: ' num2str(b)]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The right answer [given by EBH](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38788729/4960953) I just want add a detail: as you told writing legend with 2 different plot I thought about subplot, so here is the code:

```
figure
subplot(2,1,2)
plot(x,a1,x,a2)
legend('raw data', sprintf('suggested-signal: %f, suggested-filter: %f',10,20))

subplot(2,1,1)
plot(x,a2,x,a1)
legend('raw data' , spritf('again %f %f',10,20))
legend('raw data' , sprintf('again %f %f',10,20))
```

[image]